# How to respond to an email, quoting the reply

Tags: email

When an email arrives in my mail client, I can click on the reply button, and a new email is created that shows the text of the message I'm responding to, with the same subject letter as the original email.

My question is how to respond to emails in civicrm so it copies the original message's subject and quotes the original email's text?

Comment: Thanks for your question! Can you explain in a little more detail what your question is? I have no idea at the moment what you are talking about :-) Also, what version of CivICRM and what CMS you are using will help.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You want to have a reply button on 'Inbound Email' activity when clicked it will open New Email form with Subject, To, From, BCC, CC and Message will be pre-populated from  'Inbound Email' activity?

Comment: Yes. You understood correctly. I want it to be convenient to respond to incoming mail.

Comment: CiviCRM version 5.8.2. cms joomla

Comment: Hi, I know English is not your first language and I think the terms may not have translated correctly.  I think you mean: "When an email arrives in our normal email software, we simply click on the reply button and a new email is created with the history of correspondence, and the same subject as in the incoming email." Is that right? "Letter" usually refers to a piece of paper.

Comment: Yes. You understood correctly. My native Russian language.
Most likely the terms are translated incorrectly. I used google translate.
Yes. I say that it would be good if in civicrm one could just reply to letters, by analogy with the mail client.

Comment: I rewrote this to make it easier for others to understand based on the comments from  Вася.